# How to enable PHP sockets with IIS web server?

Tags: php, sockets, iis

I am using PHP 7.0.9 and I am trying to use sockets. Unfortinately it is telling me this error message:

```
Call to undefined function socket_create()
```

Apparently they are disabled in IIS? I googled it but the most recent result was dated 2008, which is 9 years old and doesn't help much in 2017.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to enable in IIS, you need to enable it in the PHP.ini file.
The error your're getting indicates the function doesn't exist, not that the function failed.

Enable the extension in the php.ini file, restart IIS and it should work.

```
Edit php.ini and remove the ";" from the line with php_sockets.dll
```

Comment: I don't have the word 'socket_ext' in my PHP.ini

Comment: @VoiDHD look for php_sockets.dll instead

Comment: I fixed it by adding a \ before the function.